# How to add time period in Android program?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an aplication for Android and I need to add "sleep time" period in my program. I don't know how to implement this. I have a sevice in my program and service must be switched off during certain periods of time (eg 22:00 - 7:00). Advise whether there is any ready solution for this kind of problem? I'm interested in is how to set this time period, thank you. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Have you tried to write a function that gets the current system time, and checks if it is in that range?

Comment: I believe that most Java programmers agree that instead of using the built-in Java date and time routines it is better to use Joda-Time. http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ But this does require that you add the Joda-Time jar file to your project.

Comment: @hexafraction I wrote my function here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25508477/3556590, it is work fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually written following function using JodaTime:

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SP_SETTINGS,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String start = sp.getString(Constants.PARAM_SLEEP_MODE_START,null);
    String end = sp.getString(Constants.PARAM_SLEEP_MODE_END,null);
    if (start==null || end ==null) return null;
    DateTime now = new DateTime(new Date());
    Days days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(new Date(0)).toLocalDate(),now.toLocalDate());
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
    DateTime begin = formatter.parseDateTime(start).plusDays(days.getDays());
    DateTime finish = formatter.parseDateTime(end).plusDays(days.getDays());
    if (begin.isAfter(finish)) {
        if (now.isBefore(finish)) begin = begin.minusDays(1);
        else  finish = finish.plusDays(1);
    } else {
        if (now.isAfter(finish)) {
            begin = begin.plusDays(1);
            finish = finish.plusDays(1);
        }
    }
    Interval interval = new Interval(begin,finish);
    return interval.contains(now);
```

It is very well defines what I want. Thank you all =)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add this to get the current date and time:

```
String str = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```

After that you can check that the time is within the range you want.

```
public static final String myformat = "HH:mm";

private Date date;
private Date time1;
private Date time2;

private String range1 = "10:00";
private String range2 = "07:00";

SimpleDateFormat str = new SimpleDateFormat(myformat, Locale.US);

private void checkRange(){
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    date = parseDate(hour + ":" + minute);
    time1= parseDate(range1);
    tim2= parseDate(range2);

    if ( time1.before( date ) && time2.after(date)) {
        //code
    }
}
```